# Using AJAX in PHP for search not working

Tags: php, ajax

i'm trying to make a live search but it's not working. the code was base on the tutorial from you tube. i wonder if this have an issue running on localhost or maybe i really have a problem on the code. this is my first time working on AJAX. whenever i'm typing some text, it doesn't show any result.

```
  ---index.php----

   <?php include ("includes/connect.php"); ?> 
   <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getClients(value){
                $.post("getClients.php",{partialClients:value},function(data)
                 $("#results").html(data);

            });

         }
        </script>
   </head>


   <body>
         <input type="text" onkeyup="getClients(this.value)"></input>
         <br>
         <div id="results"></div>

  </body>
  </html>


   -----getClients.php---

  <?php

     include "includes/connect.php"

     $partialClients= $_POST['partialClients'];
     $client = mysql_query("select * from clients WHERE client like    '%$partialClients%'  ");

     while ($clientArray = mysql_fetch_array($client)) {
        echo "<div>" .$state['client']. "</div>";
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: whats the error in console

Comment: in  getClients.php  this line `include "includes/connect.php"` should be like this `include "includes/connect.php"`;

Comment: check database fields name.. first echo every query and run it in phpmyadmin, if everything is ok than check console

Comment: `select client` and printing `$state['name']`... use `SELECT *...` and `$clientArray['name']`

Comment: my fault. i changed that already but still not working

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code: `%$partialClients%` will allow attackers to modify your query, use stored procedures (PDO) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all stop using `mysql_*` extension its deprecated and closed in PHP 7, use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

You have typo error in your PHP code on following line:

```
include "includes/connect.php" // terminate with semicolon (;)
```

You are missing semicolon on above mentioned line.

---

**Second issue** is that you are selecting `client` column only and fetching the `name` column.

Your SQL Statement only return `client` column against this query:

```
select client from clients // only return client column
```

And what you are fetching in your while loop:

```
while ($clientArray = mysql_fetch_array($client)) {
    echo "<div>" .$state['name']. "</div>";
}
```

In above example, `$state` is Undefined and this should be like:

```
while ($clientArray = mysql_fetch_array($client)) {
    echo "<div>" .$clientArray['name']. "</div>";
}
```

And your SQL Statement should be:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client LIKE '%$partialClients%'
```

Use (*) for all columns or add `name` column in your query.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

**Modified Code with Deprecated Extension:**

```
<?php
include "includes/connect.php";
$partialClients= $_POST['partialClients'];
$client = mysql_query("SELECT client FROM clients WHERE client LIKE '%$partialClients%'");

while ($clientArray = mysql_fetch_array($client)) {
   echo "<div>" .$clientArray['client']. "</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: i only need client. i changed the "name" to "client" and still. nothing changed :(

Comment: @gracia: `$state['client']` should be `$clientArray['name']`

Comment: that should be the column name right? i have table <clients> and columns are <client_ID> , <client> and <image> . i used the client column.

Comment: @gracia: if u are using (*) in your query than you need to use `$clientArray['client']` inside the while loop..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106992/discussion-between-gracia-and-devpro).